# Horizontally center images which overflows their container

Tags: html, css, image, overflow, center

I am trying to center some images (horizontally) which overflows their container divs.

The containers (and images, for that matter) have a height of 160px and I want to keep them with that height, even at smaller screen-sizes - but still keep the image horizontally centered.

I have tried `margin: 0 auto;` with no luck.

I came across an half-solution where it was suggested to use `text-align: center;` on the container div along with `margin: 0 -100%;` on the image itself. However this solution seems to only work with webkit based browsers.

In eg. Firefox the result is this:
[image: The images are moved to the left in their containers and not centered]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <a>
            <img src="image1.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <a>
            <img src="image2.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.span6{
    height: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}


.span6 img{
    height: 160px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 -100%; /*Only works for webkit based browsers*/
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

.

## EDIT:

I found out that editing `margin: 0 -100%;` to `margin: 0 -50%;` did the trick (both in Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc). However I am going with Andrey's solution since it is more likely cleaner, I assume.

Comment: add dispaly: block to img then use margin: 0 auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this will help

```
.span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I've done a quick dirty test in a code snippet and this should work.

Comment: Thank you, Andrey. It seems to work. I found out that editing `margin: 0 -100%;` to `margin: 0 -50%;` also did the trick. However your solution are more likely clean, I assume.

Comment: Much cleaner - negative margins are typically more of a "hack" and should be avoided whenever possible (for situations such as these) - do yourself a favour though and thoroughly browser test it. In any event `flex` is awesome, and leverages the computing power of the browser to calculate positioning, so you don't have to, and align accordingly. So familiarize yourself with it, you won't regret it.

Comment: Thanks @UncaughtTypeError. Actually I am experiencing that the solution above doesn't seem to work in IE? Any ideas?

Comment: Check browser support. Honestly, f**k IE, but what can we do other than set fallback styles in the event that users still use this shitty outdated browser software - we can look to the near future optimistically and hope that the userbase for this browser becomes almost obsolete - but until then you'll need to settle with fallback styles and except that it won't be perfect in those instances.

Comment: `flex` isn't well or hardly supported in IE and older versions of Safari, different syntax may be used, as this was a time when `flex` was not yet standardized and vendors implemented their own support for it. So you'll just have to take a bit of time to explore alternatives for those browsers. I usually set fallback rules before the `flex` rules (so that they don't actually overwrite the `flex` rules), so if they are not supported there is still an alternative to revert to, e.g: setting `display: inline-block`, then further down the cascade order for that style rule declaring another...

Comment: ...display rule, this time `display: flex`. You could also consider installing a browser compatibility checking script that will alert end users if they are using an outdated browser and provide links to the latest versions of better alternatives, like Firefox, Chrome or Edge. I guess it's our responsibility to inform and enable our end users to move away from these redundant browsers. End rant. (apologies for the excessive comment notifications @Andrey)

Comment: I agree, it's a pain in the ass.. For some reason, we see some of our users using that browser. I'll try experimenting with fallbacks. Thanks @UncaughtTypeError