# Horizontally center an image that overflows its container in gatsby-remark-images

Tags: html, css, centering, gatsby

I have a Gatsby.js site using `gatsby-remark-images` to process images within my markdown articles.

Articles have a fixed width, but images are overflowing on both sides:

```css
margin: 0 -15rem;
```

This works fine for large images spanning the entire width, but **smaller images aren't centered within the parent**.

I'd love to use a flexbox solution, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088234/horizontally-center-images-which-overflows-their-container), but it doesn't work because **`gatsby-remark-images` relies on `display: block;`** to properly position the base64 placeholder image along with the high-res image.

The current generated html looks like this:

```html
<span class="gatsby-resp-image-wrapper">
  <span class="gatsby-resp-image-background-image"> <!-- the base64 image is a background of this span -->
    <img
      class="gatsby-resp-image-image"
      alt="My image"
      src="/static/b07bc/my-image.jpg"
      srcset="
        /static/d942e/my-image.jpg 320w,
        /static/c1221/my-image.jpg 640w,
        /static/b07bc/my-image.jpg 1280w"
      sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"
    >
  </span>
</span>
```

And the styles:

```css
.gatsby-resp-image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /* for base64 image placeholder */
  margin: 0 -15rem; /* overflowing parent container */
  max-width: 1280px;
}

.gatsby-resp-image-background-image { /* this is the base64 image */
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,/some/url/');
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
}

.gatsby-resp-image-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

How can I horizontally center all of this?

I think there are two possible ways to solve this:

1. center the image with `margin: 0 auto;` and find another way to make it overflow the parent
2. find a way to center the image without `margin` and without `flexbox`

Any ideas?

Comment: here your missing the dot .gatsby-resp-image-image have you tried to add left:50% to images

Comment: Thanks @godfather, the dot was a typo :) The problem with the left margin is that I should add it to both the base64 placeholder image (the background of a `<span>`, and to the actual image, which is a child of the `<span>`. I'm wondering if there wouldn't be a simpler, cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

You could add an outer wrapper which handles the centering, and allow your existing image wrapper to handle the negative margin overflow.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.gatsby-resp-image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /* for base64 image placeholder */
  margin: 0 -15rem; /* overflowing parent container */
}

.gatsby-resp-image-background-image {
  /* this is the base64 image */
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
}

.gatsby-resp-image-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <span class="gatsby-resp-image-wrapper">
  <span class="gatsby-resp-image-background-image"> <!-- the base64 image is a background of this span -->
    <img
      class="gatsby-resp-image-image"
      alt="My image"
      src="https://picsum.photos/600/400"
      srcset="https://picsum.photos/600/400 320w,
        https://picsum.photos/600/400 640w,
        https://picsum.photos/600/400 1280w"
      sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"
    >
  </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This doesn't quite seem to work for me, but the opposite does: the outer wrapper handling the negative margins and the child wrapper handling centering.